# admin created record Is shared with user

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy

I created a user named"F10 manager" so I want to when the admin created the record or the existing record can not share with that user. I uncheck `view all` option in the profile (which is assigned to that user) but still not working [image][image]

any Suggestion??

Comment: what are your org-wide default sharing settings for that object? `Setup --> Sharing Settings`

Comment: public/read/write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organization-Wide Defaults (OWD) control the base level of access for records.

Profile Permissions defines what each user can do with that record, if they can access it.

In your example, `View All` and `Modify All` [override the sharing settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_object_perms.htm&type=5) so users can see/edit all records regardless if they have access to it. By turning that off, all you did was ensure that those users now abide by the OWD. Since they're `public read/write`, they will have all records shared with them.

You can see in the following image how they all come together

[image]

You'll want to set your default [sharing settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.managing_the_sharing_model.htm&type=5) to be `private`. You can then open up access through the role hierarchy or by creating sharing rules if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your time. its solved my problem